# dd can't see partition but cfdisk and GParted can

Tags: dd, gparted, cfdisk

I am working with an external HDD and trying to backup a logical partition within an extended partition using `dd` like this:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb6 of=partition6.dd
```

it returns:

```
dd: opening `/dev/sdb6': No such file or directory
```

I used the exact same method to backup a different partition (primary) with no issues

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=partition1.dd
```

Both GParted and cfdisk show sdb6 but it seems `dd` can't see it.

How can I backup `/dev/sdb6`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the device file does not exist. You can verify this by doing `ls /dev/sdb6`.

Try running the command `partprobe`, or `sudo partprobe` as user. This should detect the devices and create the according device files.

This may return the error

> Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition `/dev/sdb5` -- Device or resource busy

If it does, try to temporarily disable SELinux with `setenforce 0`, then try `partprobe` again, then don't forget to reenable SELinux.

For an external hard disk, you can also solve this error by unplugging the disk (once everything is unmounted!) and plugging it back in.

Comment: sudo partprobe returned the following:  Error: Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/sdb5 -- Device or resource busy.  This means Linux won't know about any changes you made to /dev/sdb5 until you reboot -- so you shouldn't mount it or use it in any way before rebooting.
Error: Failed to add partition 5 (Device or resource busy) ---- I'm not sure what to do with that information though.

Comment: Do you maybe have selinux enabled?

Comment: Try to temporarily disable selinux with `setenforce 0`, then try `partprobe` again, then don't forget to reenable selinux.

Comment: removing the HDD and reconnecting seems to have done the trick; dd is executing now; selinux was not enabled (checked with sestatus) - thanks

Comment: ok, great it worked